# Need to output a data file in a specific format using download handler in Rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I have a basic shiny app and I want the user to select a data set and then be able to download the selected data set without the column names. In addition, I want to add a header and a footer record to the data set being downloaded.

The header record = 0, MYFILE, 20200917.

Footer record = 9, [Number of rows in the selected data set], [sum the first column of the selected data set].

Below is the code I have so far:

ui

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel('File download'),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:", 
                  choices = c("Rock", "Pressure", "Cars")),
      radioButtons("filetype", "File type:",
                   choices = c("csv", "tsv")),
      downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('table')
    )
  )
))
```

Server:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({

    switch(input$dataset,
           "Rock" = rock,
           "Pressure" = pressure,
           "Cars" = cars)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    datasetInput()
  })
  

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    
    filename = function() {
      paste("myfile", input$dataset, gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()), "_01_res.dat_00000002", sep = ".")
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
      # Write to a file specified by the 'file' argument
      write.table(datasetInput(), file,
                  row.names = FALSE, col.names = F, sep = ",")

    }
  )
})
```

The above code works so far but without the header and footer record. when i try to add the header and footer record to the data set, it doesn't work.

I only need to change the downloadHandler part to add the footer and header record but when i do i get an error. Below is what i have tried:

```
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    
    filename = function() {
      paste("myfile", input$dataset, gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()),"_01_res.dat_00000002", sep = ".")
    },
    
    content = function(file) {
      # Write to a file specified by the 'file' argument
      a = paste0("0,","MYFILE,",gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()))
      z = paste0("9,",nrow(datasetInput), ",", sum(datasetInput))
      write.table(x = a, quote = F, sep = ",", col.names = F, row.names = F, file, sep = sep)
      write.table(x = datasetInput(), quote = F, sep = ",", col.names = F, row.names = F, append = T, file, sep = sep)
      write.table(x = z, quote = F, sep = ",", col.names = F, row.names = F, append = T, file, sep = sep)


    }
  )
```

I can achieve this in a normal R file without Shiny. the way i do it there is by writing a function and then calling the function as shown below:

Function

```
write_output <- function(a, df, z){
  filename = paste("myfile", "Rock", gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()) ,"_01_res.dat_00000002",sep = "") %>% gsub( "-", "", .)
  write.table(x = a, file = filename, quote = F, sep = ",", col.names = F, row.names = F)
  write.table(x = df, file = filename, quote = F, sep = ",", col.names = F, row.names = F, append = T)
  write.table(x = z, file = filename, quote = F, sep = ",", col.names = F, row.names = F, append = T)
}
```

Apply the function:

```
write_output(a =  paste0("0,","MyFILE,",gsub("-", "", Sys.Date())), 
             df = datasetInput, 
             z = paste0("9,",nrow(datasetInput), ",", sum(datasetInput[,1])))
```

So, in short i need to output a data set with a header and footer record which is not the same size as the data set.

Here is an example of the output - first row being the header record, followed by 3 rows from rock data set and last row is the footer

0,MyFILE,20200917

4990,2791.9,0.0903296,6.3

7002,3892.6,0.148622,6.3

7558,3930.66,0.183312,6.3

9,48,345011

Any help will be greatly appreciated :). Thanks

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: you have an bug in your code at the calculation of `z` thy this instead

      `z = paste0("9,",nrow(datasetInput()), ",", sum(datasetInput()[,1]))`

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple separators in my code which was confusing it. I took out one of the argument and it worked. Here's the new code for download Handler.

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(

```
filename = function() {
  paste("myfile", input$dataset, gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()), sep = ".")
},

content = function(file) {
  # Write to a file specified by the 'file' argument
  a = paste0("0,","MYFILE,",gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()))
  z = paste0("9,",nrow(datasetInput()), ",", sum(datasetInput()[,1]))
  write.table(x = a, quote = F, sep = ",", col.names = F, row.names = F, file)
  write.table(x = datasetInput(), quote = F, sep = ",", col.names = F, row.names = F, append = T, file)
  write.table(x = z, quote = F, sep = ",", col.names = F, row.names = F, append = T, file)
  

}
```

)